# Calculus en tan function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I got this easy problem but I do not know how to face it.
I tried to get the tangent from both side but I got nowhere. I tried to use some tangent properties but then again I missed the way.

Prove that $\tan(x)=x$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Think of $y=\tan x$ and $y=x$ graphed on the same pair of axes.  Do you know the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: if f(a)<0<f(b) so there is some $x \in[a,b]$ such that f(x)=0

Comment: But I am not sure how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that in every interval $I_{k} = ]k \frac{\pi}{2}, (k +1)\frac{\pi}{2}[$ the function $f(x) = \text{tan}(x)$ is continuous and ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. In the same interval the function $g(x) = x$ ranges from $-k\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $(k + 1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ so there are two numbers $x_{1}, x_{2} \in I_{k}$ such that $x_{1} < x_{2}$, $f(x_{1}) < g(x_{1})$ and $f(x_{2}) > g(x_{2})$.

If we define the new function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ this means that $h(x_{1}) < 0$ and $h(x_{2}) > 0$, since $h$ is continuous in $I_{k}$ (difference of continous functions) there exists $y \in I_{k}$ such that $h(y) = 0$ (We're using the intermediate value theorem). From that it follows $f(y) = g(y)$.

Since we have found such an $y$ for every interval $I_{k}$ we have proved that the equation $\text{tan}(x) = x$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: is it obvious that exist x1,x2∈Ik  such that x1<x2, f(x1)<g(x1) and f(x2)>g(x2).?

Comment: @Paul It's because the range of $f$ in $I_{k}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, while the range of $g$ it's only $I_{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

At $x=n\pi, \tan x = 0 < x.$  Now $\lim_{x\to (n\pi +\pi/2)+} = \infty$ so for some value $n\pi < x<n\pi+\pi/2, x<\tan x$  Since $f(x)=x-\tan x$ is continuous on $(n\pi, n\pi+\pi/2)$ the is a point $x$ in this interval where $x=\tan x$

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that

- $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}, \, \tan x$ for $x\in I_k=(-\pi/2+k\pi,\pi/2+k\pi)$ is continuos, surjective and strictly increasing
- then $\forall k\in \mathbb{Z},\,f(x)=\tan x-x$ intersect $x$ axis exactly once

thus $\tan x = x$ has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the graph of $$y=\tan (x)$$ has infinitely many vertical asymptotes and between any two of these asymptotes the graph covers the entire $$y=(-\infty, \infty)$$

Thus  between any two consecutive asymptotes the  graph of $y=x$ meets the graph of $y=\tan(x)$

That is infinitely many intersections.